# MVC Action calling another action doesn't trigger OnActionExecuting

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have some custom ActionFilterAttributes setup in my application, and using OnActionExecuting to do some checks. It works fine, except when I run an action from within the controller:

```
public class CarBoardController : GlobalController
{
    [HttpPost, ActionProperties(AccessLevel.Granted)]
    public ActionResult CarBoard(int carId)
    {
        var carModel = _businessLogic.GetCarForCarId(carId);

        if (carModel == null)
        {
            // if null create one
            carModel = CreateCarForCarId(carId);
        }

        var model = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(carModel);

        return PartialView(new CarViewModel(model));
    }

    [ActionProperties(AccessLevel.Admin)]
    public ICarBoardNode CreateCarForCarId(int carId)
    {
        return _businessLogic.CreateCarForCarId(carId);
    }
}

public class GlobalController : Controller
{
    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

`OnActionExecuting` is hit once right before `CarBoard` which then calls `CreateCarForCarId` but never hits OnActionExecuting.

My businessLogic contains the check to make sure that only admins can create cars, but I would have thought this would allow me to not even have to hit the businessLogic.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OnActionExecuting` is part of the MVC pipeline. Your action isn't calling another action, your action is calling a method that defines what an action does. That sounds like splitting hairs, but the difference is the cause of the behavior you are seeing.

I would do some refactoring here to accomplish what you are looking for.

```
public class CarBoardController : GlobalController
{
    [HttpPost, ActionProperties(AccessLevel.Granted)]
    public ActionResult CarBoard(int carId)
    {
        var carModel = _businessLogic.GetCarForCarId(carId);

        if (carModel == null)
        {
            PermissionChecker.CheckPermission(AccessLevel.Admin);
            carModel = CreateCarForCarId(carId);
        }

        var model = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(carModel);

        return PartialView(new CarViewModel(model));
    }

    [ActionProperties(AccessLevel.Admin)]
    public ICarBoardNode CreateCarForCarId(int carId)
    {
        return _businessLogic.CreateCarForCarId(carId);
    }
}

public class GlobalController : Controller
{
    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        PermissionChecker.CheckPermission(/* get desired access here  */);
    }
}

public class PermissionChecker
{
    public void CheckPermission(AccessLevel level)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: That's what I had in mind next but I was curious if there might be another solution... guess not! Thank you!